# Append file to file in bash without cat

Tags: bash, file, append

It's easy to append an existing file to another file with `cat`: `cat file1 >> file2`

Sometimes I have read what people wrote, "do not use `cat` unless you are concatenating two files." This is sensible. One does not really need cat if it is taking only one argument: `cat file | xargs program` is worse than `xargs program < file`.

So how do I append a file to another file without cat? Neither `< file1 >> file2` nor `>> file2 < file1` work. If I must call a program to do this, what is the orthodox way?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the prohibition; you shouldn't use `cat` if all you are doing is piping the contents of *one* file to another command, in which case input redirection is more appropriate. Here, `cat` is the *only* program involved.

Comment: Here you **are concatenating two files**, so it is A-OK.

Comment: Now if this were `zsh`, I'd say "Yeah, it's a useless use of `cat`, use `<file1 >>file2` instead." :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This *is* an orthodox use of `cat`. The "useless use of `cat`" involves using `cat` to read the contents of a *single* file and pipe them to another program which could just as easily read directly from the file using input redirection. Here, `cat` is doing all the reading *and* writing; there isn't anything simpler you could replace it with, since `bash` does not provide a built-in that reads from standard input *and* writes to standard output.

Comment: I know that this is over a year old, but I stumbled upon it and I just wanted to mention that while I don't know of any `bash` builtin which reads stdin and writes to stdout I do know that `awk` is perfectly acceptable to output stdin to stdout and since its purpose is not to concatenate files, it easily avoids the `UUOC`. Note that the default pattern matches all lines and the default action is to write the line, so `awk file` will accomplish the same thing as `cat file` but without the UUOC dilema.

Comment: `awk file` is basically the same as `cat`. If one is appropriate, so is the other. If one is inappropriate, so is the other. The goal is not to avoid `cat` in particular, but *any* external process that can be replaced by a simple input redirection. (Some implementations of `awk` might require at least a pattern or an action, such as `awk 1 file` or `awk '{print}' file`.)

Answer (score 2):

With the `tee` command, you can append to files.

```
tee file1 --append < file2 > /dev/null
```

You can also use `dd`

```
dd status=none of=file1 oflag=append conv=notrunc,nocreat if=file2
```

This last one is cheating a bit, but we can also abuse file descriptors like this:

```
exec 5>>file1; tail -qn +1 file2 >&5
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
# Redirecting Input 'from' file to Command Substitution as "echo" argument
# "echo" stdout write 'to' file
echo "$(<from)" > to

# Redirecting Input 'from' file to Command Substitution as "printf" argument
# "printf" stdout write 'to' file
printf "%s" "$(<from)" > to

# Redirecting Input 'from' file to "sed" and stdout write 'to' file
sed -n '/.*/p' <from > to
```

> **envsubst**
> In normal operation mode, standard input is copied to standard
> output, with references to environment variables of the form ‘$VARIABLE’`
> or ‘${VARIABLE}’ being replaced with the corresponding values.

```sh
# create file with name 'template'
echo '$buf' > template

# Redirecting Input 'from' file to Command Substitution 
# Assign to 'buf' variable and export 
# envsubst standard input from 'template' file copied 'to' file
export buf="$(<from)" && envsubst < template > to
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
while read line
do
    echo $line
done < file1 >> file2
```

Comment: You can (if you do it correctly: `IFS= read -r line` and `echo "$line"` or `printf "%s" "$line"`), but why bother? There's nothing wrong with using `cat` in this situation, it's far easier to type, and it will probably be faster than trying to read the file line-by-line in shell.

Answer (score 0):

Using `echo` with file redirect:

```
for f in /path/file1 /path/file2 /path/file3
do
    echo "$(<"$f")"
done >> /path/destination
```

Remember to properly quote your input array if needed.

Explanation: `$(<"$f")` creates an argument to `echo` using the contents of file `$f`.